# Dynamic path name for image tag

Tags: reactjs, image, error-handling, react-hooks, path

I am trying to pass the path name to the image dynamically, But I have an error.

This works:

```
  return (
<div className='single-employee'>
  {singleEmployee && (
    <div>{avatar && <img src={require(`../../uploads/1.png`)} alt='' />}</div>
  )}
</div
```

This doesn't

```
const path = "/uploads/1.png";


 return (
<div className='single-employee'>
  {singleEmployee && (
    <div>{avatar && <img src={require(`../..${path}`)} alt='' />}</div>
  )}
</div>
```

It gives me an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './../uploads/1.png'
at webpackEmptyContext (..*$:2:1)
at SingleEmployee (SingleEmployee.jsx:33:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are getting error `jpeg` image, while you are giving `png` image.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Import { anyName } from '../../uploads/1.png';

<img src={anyName} />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).